# Observable not emitting any values

Tags: rxjs, nativescript, ngrx

I have an Observable of an array of objects that has been returned from a web api call.

I am creating another observable by running some pipeable operators over it such as filter. I know that the condition will not meet any current items in the array, however I would still like to receive a default value, as the resultant observable is meant to be used in a call to `combineLatest` further down the track and the `combineLatest` will not work unless at least one value has been emitted.

No matter what I do, I cannot get this observable to emit a value if none of the items in the original array meet the filter requirements. See below some of the approaches I have taken

```
this.firstItem$ = this.items$
                      .pipe(map(xArray => xArray.filter(x => x.prop === true)),
                            flatMap(x => x),
                            defaultIfEmpty(null as Item));
```

When I subscribe to `this.firstItem$`, nothing is emitted

I have even tried to `concat` an empty/null item to `this.firstItem$` and still nothing emits

```
this.firstItem$ = this.items$
                      .pipe(
                            flatMap(x => x),
                            filter(item => item.prop === true),
                            concat(of(null as Item)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source Observable must be completed before **defaultIfEmpty** or **concat** emits their value.

To complete the source Observable you can pipe operators like: take, takeUntil (before defaultIfEmpty/concat)

Comment: Will take work if no items are returned from the filter?

Comment: No. But you can pipe it before the filter if that fits your use case